# How do I right align a search bar in a Java SWT Unified ToolBar (OS X)

Tags: java, macos, swt, alignment, toolbar

How would one go about to align an item to the right in a Java SWT unified toolbar under OS X? 
I don't want to align all the items to the right but rather just the search field. The question marked as a duplicate does not answer this but rather just how you align all toolbaritems to the right with a "common nonunified toolbar", hence it's not the same problem.

Also if someone knows how I can use the system buttons from finder for view, back and forward it would be much appreciated as I don't really like what it looks like now.

This is what I have: 
[image: What I have]

And this is what I want:[image: This is what I want]

Comment: Vulcan: I tried that however it doesn't work with the Unified SWT Toolbar in OS X and even when using a common toolbar it aligns all items to the right rather then just one.

Comment: This really isn't a dup.  An SWT `Toolbar` is not the Mac OS Unified Toolbar...!

Answer (score -1):

```
org.eclipse.ui.menus.MenuUtils
```

has predefined position constants that you can use. Hope it helps!

http://eclipse-rcp-development.blogspot.com/2012/08/where-to-find-menutoolbar-uri-constants.html

Comment: This is not the same. These constants are used to add items to menus and toolbars at a specific position in the menu or toolbar. It has no influence on the visual alignment of the item.